# Are these two logic statements equivalent? If not, why?

Tags: logic

I'm starting out learning logic, and worked out (and checked) that the answer to a question in my textbook is:

((¬A → ¬B) ∧ (A → B))

It got me thinking that this is very close, if not exactly the same, as saying:

((A ∧ B) ∨ (¬A ∧ ¬B))

Is that the case? If not, why?

(For reference, the question (paraphrased) is 5.C.8 in forallx: Cambridge)

Comment: Have you checked it with truth table?

Comment: Your "intuition" is fine: they are equivalent.

Comment: I haven't learned about truth tables yet. Thank you very much for confirming they're the same though!

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA from truth table it comes out equal. But I am having difficulty proving it syntactically i.e. only through associativity, commutativity, distributivity and de morgan's. How may one do that ?

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
(\neg A \rightarrow \neg B )&\land (A \rightarrow B)\\
(A \lor \neg B )&\land (\neg A \lor B)\\
\end{align}
Distributing $(A \lor \neg B )$ over $(\neg A \lor B)$ :
\begin{align}
((A \lor \neg B ) \land \neg A )&\lor ((A \lor \neg B )\land B)\\
\end{align}
Distributivity:
\begin{align}
((\neg A \land A) \lor (\neg B \land \neg A ))&\lor ((B \land \neg B )\lor (B\land A))\\
(\neg B \land \neg A )&\lor (B\land A))\\
\end{align}